# Jest / react-testing-library / React - unable to find an element.. with async calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I am getting this error, for this test:

***Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="detail-result"]***

```
import { render, screen, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import Comp1 from "./Comp1";
import { DataProvider } from "./Context";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

describe("Comp1 tests", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  it("Should give correct response with render", async () => {
    render(
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <DataProvider>
          <Comp1 />
        </DataProvider>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    );
    expect(await screen.findByTestId("detail-result")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

afterEach(cleanup);
```

I know it is something to do with the api call waiting for the other one to finish, but even with async/await I get the error:

recreated here: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-fast-g495f?file=/src/Comp1.test.js)

Comment: Just looking through it all now but is there a reason why you are doing the same api call twice? within the `DataProvider` and `Comp1`. Seems really unnecessary

Comment: So the Context (Data Provider) gets the first query i.e. the todos and gets the ID the comp1 component then gets the detail for the todos based on the id, so they are 2 different api calls